# Django (1.6.3) Model.save() method not working

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have below django model (with managed=False).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user')
    last_modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='last_modified_by', null=True)
    last_modified_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

when I execute 'python manage.py shell' and type in below two statements, I could see the row added in the mysql db.

```
>>> dm = MyModel(name='name1', description='test1', client_id=6,user_id=9,last_modified_by_id=9)
>>> dm.save()
```

But when I run the server 'python manage.py runserver' and execute the same statement in a class method, the save() goes through but there is no new row added in the DB.

```
    def funcname(self, request):
        print("Creating new row...")
        self.var = MyModel(name='testName',description='testDescription',client_id=6, user=9, last_modified_by=9)
        self.var.save()
        print("Created new row')
```

Observations:

- The two print statements do get printed on the console. But no entry in the db.
- No error/exception in the funcname().
- Tried with giving unique entries for diff columns. Same result
- When ran the server with pdb.set_trace() at the beginning of the function, it was found the MyModel.objects.filter() gives right number of rows. But this number does not match when looked in the db.

  (Pdb) MyModel.objects.filter()

  shows list of 2 MyModel objects.

But when checked by logging into DB, the corresponding table has only 1 row.

Using Python 2.7

Any pointers on what may be going on ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try printing `print(self.var.id)` after the save has been executed?

Comment: Yes. It prints the id rightly.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right database and not an sqlite db for example?

Comment: Yes it is the right and same mysql db. As I mentioned, I could see new row inserted when I used 'python manage.py shell'. Something is definitely weird here.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary key is an IntegerField, which means that Django doesn't know it is supposed to autoincrement. Therefore it isn't setting a value automatically.

Change the definition to use an AutoField instead.

Comment: Or leave it out entirely; django automatically adds a id for any model that doesn't have one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Answer (score 1):

After digging a bit more, I found that somewhere in the caller, transaction.atomic decorator was used. This was causing the write to db table to fail. I am updating this here hoping that this will help someone in future.

Thanks to all who replied.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following

```
    def funcname(self, request):
        self.var = MyModel.objects.create(name='testName',description='testDescription',client_id=6, user=9, last_modified_by=9)
```

And Daniel commented about the id/pk field Django adds that automatically so no need to redeclare the field.